# OLS summary values change on every run

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels

I am new to data analysis. I am running OLS with multiple X. The model is generation fine but I get different R2 value and values the independent variable change on every run.

Change in R2 is very small bit coeff or P>|t| for independent variables vary a lot. Is this expected? If not, what I am I doing wrong?

````
X = train[['GarageCars','YearBuilt']]
y = train["SalePrice"]
X = sm.add_constant(X) 
model_1 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions_1 = model_1.predict(X)

X1 = test[['GarageCars','YearBuilt']]
y1 = test["SalePrice"]
X1 = sm.add_constant(X) 
predictions_2 = model_1.predict(X1)
model_1.summary()```

thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Ahh found it. I was splitting the data again every time I ran the model code.